# Is the changeling's Shapechange ability detectable with Detect Magic?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic, racial-traits

In one of the Unearthed Arcana, the changeling from Eberron was introduced as a playable character race. It has a "shapechange" ability, which allows for a superficial polymorph to change their appearance.

Is this change detectable with a Detect Magic spell? Or is there any other way to detect the changeling's use of this ability?

Comment: Is this question about the version of the changeling that appeared in the very first Unearthed Arcana, [UA: Eberron](https://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/UA_Eberron_v1.1.pdf), back in 2015? Your question seems to have been posted a few months before the initial release of *Wayfinder's Guide to Eberron* and the corresponding playtest in [UA: Races of Eberron](https://dnd.wizards.com/articles/unearthed-arcana/races-eberron), where an updated version of the race appeared (before *Eberron: Rising from the Last War* was released with the published final version in 2019).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Detect Magic will not identify a polymorphed Changeling.

Only spells (or abilities that replicate specific spell effects or invoke a "spell attack"), magical items, and effects specifically clarified as being magical by descriptive text count as capital-M Magic, which would be detected by *Detect Magic*. Otherwise, even something which would seem supernatural to us is just part of the "background magic" of the world, which is a part of nature and always functions, and is not considered magical as far as game rules are concerned (as per [Sage Advice](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/rules-answers-february-2016)).

The changeling's *Shapechanger* ability states:

> ***Shapechanger.*** As an action, you can polymorph into any humanoid of your size that you have seen, or back into your true form. However, your equipment does not change with you. If you die, you revert to your natural appearance.

Contrast with, for instance, the *Change Shape* ability of certain dragons, which always has wording like:

> **Change Shape**: The dragon magically polymorphs into a humanoid or beast that has a challenge rating no higher than its own, or back into its true form.

The dragon's ability is expressly magical. The Changeling's ability is not. Therefore, effects that detect magic are no use in identifying a polymorphed changeling, though they would help you spot a polymorphed dragon.

### There are, however, other means to identify a polymorphed Changeling.

Any being with *Truesight* can:

> see in normal and magical darkness, see invisible creatures and objects, automatically detect visual illusions and succeed on saving throws against them, **and perceive the original form of a shapechanger** or a creature that is transformed by magic

The most obvious way to gain Truesight is the use of the 6th-level spell *True Seeing*.

The spell *Moonbeam* also has an extra effect when it targets shapechangers, as failing to save against the spell forces them to resume their original form - though this is a damaging spell, so probably not one to use unless you're already on very bad terms with your suspected polymorphee.

Comment: I think it is perfectly reasonable to have *detect magic* go "ping" if it detects a disguised changeling or other shape-shifter. But how useful is this, really? The spell says that it shows a magical aura around a creature from 30 feet away and reveals the magic's school. Great. But magic is everywhere in any campaign. Is the person a disguised changeling? Or are they another magical creature? Wearing a magic item? From a class that gives them a permanent magical effect?  A changeling's shape-shifting does not have a school given, so it should just detect as generic.

Comment: Oh, and you can be sure that the changeling knows this and will always disguise itself as someone who could plausibly have a magical aura. "Oh, yes, it's this magic cloak that I inherited from my mother, been in the family for generations." The spell also takes an action and consumes a spell slot if not cast as a fairly time-consuming ritual, and requires concentration otherwise, so no one will be casting it too regularly without some reason for suspicion—something the changeling can certainly rely upon.

Comment: Also, a thirty-foot range is not much at all. It will detect the concealed changeling in the party if they made the mistake of disguising themself as someone who could not have a generic magic aura, sure. But it won't detect that the mayor has been replaced by a changeling if the party never gets near them.

Comment: Or the changeling can just fight back with more magic, like *Nystul's magic aura*, which is only one level higher.

Comment: Anyway, when players get spells that are just one level higher, they get *detect thoughts*, which will automatically give away surface thoughts (better hope the changeling is thinking something appropriate to its disguise at the time!) and likely give away the whole game immediately if the target fails a Wisdom saving throw.