# Does the Shapechanger trait work in an Antimagic Field?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic, shapeshifting, antimagic-field

Certain monsters have the Shapechanger trait. For instance, here it is on the Werewolf:

> **Shapechanger.** The werewolf can use its action to polymorph into a wolf-humanoid hybrid or into a wolf, or back into its true form, which is humanoid. Its Statistics, other than its AC, are the same in each form. Any Equipment it is wearing or carrying isn't transformed. It reverts to its true form if it dies.

I note that nowhere in this description is the word "magical" found.

Contrast this with a metallic dragon's Change Shape feature, which does feature the word "magical".

> **Change Shape.** The dragon *magically* polymorphs into a humanoid or beast that has a challenge rating no higher than its own, or back into its true form.

**In an Antimagic Field, can a Werewolf use its Shapechanger trait?**

Comment: Not a duplicate, but related: [Is the changeling's Shapechange ability detectable with Detect Magic?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/120819/is-the-changelings-shapechange-ability-detectable-with-detect-magic)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

### The Shapechanger trait is not affected by antimagic field

The [Sage Advice Compendium](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf) tells us how to determine whether a feature is magical (p. 17, "Is the breath weapon of a dragon magical?"):

> Determining whether a game feature is  magical is straightforward. Ask yourself these questions  about the feature:
>
> - Is it a magic item?
> - Is it a spell? Or does it let you create the effects of a spell 
>     that’s mentioned in its description?
> - Is it a spell attack?
> - Is it fueled by the use of spell slots?
> - Does its description say it’s magical?
>
> If your answer to any of those questions is yes, the feature 
>   is magical.

Let's answer each of these questions for the Shapechanger trait:

- **Is it a magic item?** No
- **Is it a spell? Or does it let you create the effects of a spell 
  that’s mentioned in its description?** There is nothing in the description that indicates this
- **Is it a spell attack?** No
- **Is it fueled by the use of spell slots?** No
- **Does its description say it’s magical?** Searching through the description of both the ability and the lore there is no mention of it being magical

So we can conclude that the Shapechanger trait is not magical and thus not affected by an antimagic field. This means that a werewolf can use the shapechanger trait inside an antimagic field as usual.

Answer (score 0):

## The Shapechanger trait is affected by antimagic field

### How to determine if something is magical

If we go through the questions in the Sage Advice companion: *"Is the breath weapon of a dragon magical?"*  There are a few questions te determine if something is magical or not:

> - Is it a magic item?
> - Is it a spell? Or does it let you create the effects of a spell 
>     that’s mentioned in its description?
> - Is it a spell attack?
> - Is it fueled by the use of spell slots?
> - Does its description say it’s magical?
>
> If your answer to any of those questions is yes, the feature 
>   is magical.

### Sage advice: Breath weapon

> **Cold Breath** (Recharge 5-6): The dragon exhales an icy blast in a 60-foot cone. Each creature in that area must make a DC 19 Constitution saving throw, taking 54 (12d8) cold damage on a failed save, or half as much damage on a successful one.

Sage advice:

> Let’s look at a white dragon’s Cold Breath and ask our
>   - selves those questions.
>
> First, Cold Breath isn’t a magic  item.
>
> Second, its description mentions no spell.
>
> Third, it’s  not a spell
>   attack.
>
> Fourth, the word “magical” appears no
>   - where in its description.
>
> Our conclusion: Cold Breath is not  considered a magical game effect, even though we know  that dragons
>   are amazing, supernatural beings.

### Our case: Shapechanger trait

- **Is it a magic item?** No
- **Is it a spell? Or does it let you create the effects of a spell 
  that’s mentioned in its description?** Yes: (emphasis mine)

> **Shapechanger**.
>
> The werewolf can use its action to **polymorph into a wolf-humanoid hybrid or into a wolf, or back into its true form, which is humanoid.** Its Statistics, other than its AC, are the same in each form. Any Equipment it is wearing or carrying isn't transformed. It reverts to its true form if it dies.

Now let's look at Polymorph:(emphasis mine)

> **Polymorph**
>
> **This spell transforms a creature that you can see within 
>   range into a new form.** An unwilling creature must make a Wisdom saving
>   throw to avoid the effect. **A shapechanger automatically succeeds on
>   this saving throw.**
>
> The transformation lasts for the duration, or until the target drops
>   to 0 hit points or dies. The new form can be any beast whose challenge
>   rating is equal to or less than the target’s (or the target’s level,
>   if it doesn’t have a challenge rating). The target’s game statistics,
>   including mental ability scores, are replaced by the statistics of the
>   chosen beast. It retains its alignment and personality.
>
> The target assumes the hit points of its new form. When it reverts to
>   its normal form, the creature returns to the number of hit points it
>   had before it transformed. If it reverts as a result of dropping to 0
>   hit points, any excess damage carries over to its normal form. As long
>   as the excess damage doesn’t reduce the creature’s normal form to 0
>   hit points, it isn’t knocked unconscious.
>
> The creature is limited in the actions it can perform by the nature of
>   its new form, and it can’t speak, cast spells, or take any other
>   action that requires hands or speech.
>
> The target’s gear melds into the new form. The creature can’t
>   activate, use, wield, or otherwise benefit from any of its equipment.
>   This spell can’t affect a target that has 0 hit points.  As you can
>   see, it lists both a spell (polymorph) and the effects of an spell
>   (polymorph).

### Conclusion

The 2nd question of the sage advice answers yes, and thus is considered magical. The shapechanger even has an specifically notation in the polymorph spell.

With this information we can conclude that the Shapechanger trait is magical and affected by an antimagic field, the werewolf would revert back to humanoid when in a antimagic field.

### Personal Opinion

Because the rules are unclear, it can be interperted in different ways.

Personally I would rule it as supernatural, since the cause of the transformation is lycantrophy (werewolf disease).

But as in all D&D games, the DM can decide the interpertation of the rules.

Comment: I don't think *polymorph* is referring to the spell in this case. To me it sounds like it is just used as a verbe to describe the action. It does not state "like the spell polymorph" or "like casting polymorph".

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103686/discussion-on-answer-by-inferno-iv-does-the-shapechanger-trait-work-in-an-antima).

Comment: @ArtificialSoul  If it were meant to be "just used as a verb", the correct verb would be 'morph'; 'The werewolf can use its action to morph into..."  Morph means to change or transform, and the addition of the root _poly_ implies that the transformation is capable of achieving many different forms, whereas the werewolf has only three.  Grammatically, it appears to be a reference to the spell, but that could just be poor writing.

Answer (score -2):

I would agree it is magical. It was far clearer in 3.5 when it labeled effects like these as supernatural (su) and then clearly defined the term supernatural, as not being dispellable but considered magical for antimagic. If it weren't magical and wanted to reverse from being semi magical in an earlier version to being non magical in 5e, it shouldn't have referenced a spell directly and been more clear imo. But most people that have only ever played 5e tend to concur with the reasoning that it isn't magical in nature at all. But do remember that if they revert back to a form after they're dead, then something had to be holding the effect in place. 5e has no supernatural designator so it's completely up to DM on how to work it, even if they did consider it magical. It's entirely hands in the air and up to DM in 5e.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already.