# Can an Aasimar grow their wings in an Antimagic Field?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, racial-traits, antimagic-field, aasimar

One of my players wants to play a [Protector Aasimar](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/races/aasimar#ProtectorAasimar) (VGtM, p. 105) but wondered if he'd be able to use his racial ability, Radiant Soul, in an *antimagic field*.

Would an *antimagic field* block the protector aasimar's Radiant Soul feature, or would he be unaffected?

Comment: Related: [How do I know if an ability is magical?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/113364/33707)

Comment: You may want to give it a day or two before accepting the answer. While I think the accepted answer is wholly correct, having such a quickly accepted answer may dissuade others from contributing.

Comment: I've unaccepted it, you're right. I got a bit too excited about getting the answer that made a lot of sense.

Comment: I believe this is also related: [does the shapechanger trait work in an antimagic field](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/128779/does-the-shapechanger-trait-work-in-an-antimagic-field)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

## Yes, Aasimar can use this ability in an *antimagic field*

Only magic and magical effects are affected by an *anti-magic field* as indicated in the description of the spell:

> Spells and other magical effects, except those created by an artifact or deity, are suppressed in the sphere and can't protrude into it.

[Sage Advice](http://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf) gives us tests for determining if something is considered magical. I will go through and apply these tests to the Radiant Soul ability.

> - Is it a magic item?

Nope.

> - Is it a spell? Or does it let you create the effects of a spell
>   that’s mentioned in its description?

It is not a spell and no spell is mentioned in its description. See [this Q&A](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/131495/what-counts-as-a-spell) for a description of how to tell if something is a spell.

> - Is it a spell attack?

It isn't a spell or an attack so no.

> - Is it fueled by the use of spell slots?

It uses no spell slots.

> - Does its description say it’s magical?

Nowhere in the description does it say it is magical.

The Aasimar ability Radiant Soul passes none of these tests and is thus not magical. Since it is not magical it is not affected by *antimagic field*.

Comment: It also makes sense lore wise as an antimagic field blocks access to the magical forces in the universe, not the innate magic of an Aasimar.

Comment: @qazwsx AMF will block even innate magic if it is described as magic. However this is a supernatural ability that is not magic (innate or otherwise). But yeah it does seem to make sense that it doesn't block instead abilities like this.

Comment: No. And for the same reason, undead do not fall apart in an antimagic field. Apparently, the magic that animates them (failing the last test in Rubiksmoose's answer above) doesn't count as a magical effect.

Comment: @MarkTO: Depending on the undead the reason is also that oftentimes the magic that reanimated them has instantaneous and thus has no lasting trace on them and thus nothing for the AMF to suppress.